# Issues with Powershell variables/expressions

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to build a Get-Winevent command using variables, but I'm having issues with variables inside "built" commands and I've hit the proverbial brick wall. On the last bit of code, if I remove `$EventIDQueryAdd` and `$EntryTypeQueryAdd` the command runs without issue. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
$ArgLastMinutes = 60
$ArgLogName = "Security"
$ArgEntryType = 0 
$ArgEventID = 4625
if ($ArgEventID) { $EventIDQueryAdd="id=$ArgEventID;" }
if ($ArgEntryType) { $EntryTypeQueryAdd="level=$ArgEntryType;" }

write-host "argeventid "$ArgEventID # returns 4625
write-host "argentrytype "$ArgEntryType # returns 1
write-host "eventidqueryadd "$EventIDQueryAdd # returns id=4625; as it should
write-host "entrytypequeryadd "$EntryTypeQueryAdd # returns level=1; as it should
$LogEntries=Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="$ArgLogName"; $EventIDQueryAdd $EntryTypeQueryAdd StartTime=(Get-Date).AddMinutes(-$ArgLastMinutes) }
```

... <loop through LogEntries> ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to build a hashtable like a string, it wouldn't work that way. When you say `returns id=4625; as it should` it's not true, you've got a string here, not a hashtable. For a hashtable you should see this output:

```
Name    Value
----    -----
Id      4625
```

Try this:

```powershell
$ArgLastMinutes = 60
$ArgLogName = 'Security'
$ArgEntryType = 0 
$ArgEventID = 4625

# Create a new hashtable with two keys
$Filter = @{
    LogName = $ArgLogName
    StartTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-$ArgLastMinutes)
}

if($ArgEventID)
{
    # Add new key-value pair to the existing hashtable
    $Filter += @{Id = $ArgEventID}
}

if($ArgEntryType)
{
    # Add new key-value pair to the existing hashtable
    $Filter += @{Level = $ArgEntryType}
}

# Pass the hashtable to the -FilterHashtable parameter
$LogEntries = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $Filter
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for your assistance!